# Create Tables on Azure database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I have just created a server and a database on an instance of Azure.

What are my options in terms of adding tables to this (without using Entity Framework at least for the time being)

Can I use either SSMS or SSDT? Is there any preferred option between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either, the preferred depends entirely on your requirements which, unfortunelty, are somewhat lacking from your question :)

Ed

Comment: Thanks. Yes at the moment I need to just create some tables :-) but i get your point... he he

Comment: in the azure portal there is a query tool that will let you run queries (create table etc) from there so you don't event need ssms / ssdt :)